# How does Facebook Android SDK deal with access toke expiration?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I want to integrate Facebook's Android SDK into my app. When user first time logs into my app using Facebook, he needs to enter the password and grant the permissions. I understand the access token will expire in 60 days. However, after 60 days, when user starts the app again, does he need to log into Facebook again with entering the password or actually the token will be automatically renewed?

Answer (score 0):

If the user (or your app) accesses the Graph API within 60 days, then the token will be auto-renewed.

If the user opens the app after 60 days (after the token as already expired), then they will need to log in again.